# Snowpack and postcss-import?

Tags: postcss, snowpack, postcss-import

I'm trying to use [`postcss-simple-vars`](https://github.com/postcss/postcss-simple-vars) with [Snowpack](https://www.snowpack.dev/).

**REPL**: https://github.com/frederikhors/snowpack-svelte-tailwindcss

I'm using https://github.com/snowpackjs/snowpack/tree/main/create-snowpack-app/app-template-svelte-typescript

I'm trying to use it like this:

- postcss.config.js:

```js
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    require('postcss-import'),
    require('postcss-simple-vars'),
    require('tailwindcss'),
    require('autoprefixer'),
    ...(production ? [require('cssnano')] : [])
  ],
};
```

- index.js:

```js
import "./index.css";
```

- index.css:

```css
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;

@import "./colors.css";

@tailwind utilities;

body {
  background-color: $my-custom-bgcolor;
}
```

- colors.css:

```css
$my-custom-bgcolor: #ff0000;
```

but it can't find the vars, why?

```
Error: Command failed with exit code 1: postcss
CssSyntaxError: postcss-simple-vars: C:\project\stdin:28:3: Undefined variable $my-custom-bgcolor
```

**Can you help me?**

**UPDATE**:

I read all https://github.com/snowpackjs/snowpack/discussions/1693 and tried everything: I HAD NO LUCK!

I can't import nested .css with `@import` as:

```css
@import "./colors.css";
```

nor as:

```css
@import "colors.css";
```

As a consequence of this I am unable to use `postcss-simple-vars`.

Comment: Where is that `production` variable coming from?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found a solution, that worked for me:

1. remove the `postcss-import` plugin: The import is done by Snowpack.
2. everywhere use relative paths (`./colors.css` or `../../colors.css`)
3. `@import` your variables file everywhere where variables are used
4. switch from `postcss-simple-vars` to `postcss-custom-properties`

I'm not sure if step 3 and step 4 are necessary, at least that worked for me. The code also looks cleaner with `properties` instead of `simple vars`.

Comment: I've sent a pull request with a fix of your repo. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your work. But `postcss-simple-vars` isn't quite similar to `postcss-custom-properties`, isn't it?

Comment: What do you mean with: `The import is done by Snowpack.`? Why are you importing from `dist`? `@import "/dist/style/tailwind.css";` and `@import "/dist/style/colors.css";`?